# How To Make Partial Blur Effect in React Native

Tags: react-native, blur

I'm trying to create a 'focus' effect on images in React Native, but I'm unable to create this effect using Blur and Overlay.

Does anyone know how it might be done .. ?

Here's an example of what I had in mind:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is a valid approach for your needs, but this could be accomplished by rendering the image twice. The first image is the blurred background. Blur the whole thing. Then overlay a non-blurred image and offset it so it aligns properly. You can add border radius to make it round.

Comment: @TravisWhite, thank you very much for the suggestion! Any change to get a code snippet that I might be able to start testing with?

Comment: @EladA hi did you manage to make it work ???

Answer (score 1):

use MaskedView from `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` along with BlurView from `@react-native-community/blur` to get this result

[snack link](https://snack.expo.dev/@ashwith00/thoughtful-cereal)

result:
[image]

code:

```
export default function App() {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MakedView
        style={{ width, height, alignItems: 'center' }}
        maskElement={
          <BlurView
            tint="dark"
            intensity={54}
            style={{
              width,
              height,
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            <View
              style={{
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                borderRadius: 100,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
              }}></View>
          </BlurView>
        }>
        <Image
          style={{ width, height, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
          source={{
            uri: 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg',
          }}
        />
      </MakedView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout the `react-native-blur` library.

Their example shows a blurred background with buttons on top. You could easily place an image on the blur instead of buttons.

Hope that helps.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur

Comment: Thank you for your answer Corey, I'm afraid this isn't quite what I'm after (gave it a shot). For the time being, we're rendering the image on the server side using Pillow and CV

Answer (score 0):

`npm i react-native-blur-overlay` use this library and there are several properties to partially blur your images accordingly how you need it.